# A Model, a ListView, and a DetailView

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to understand SwiftUI and have a simple app in mind to help me learn. My app has one model and two views, shown below.

The first question is specific: how do I get "update tournament" to work? I can't figure out which, if any, variable I should bind to or if that's even the right approach.

```
struct Tournament { // eventually will have more properties, such as Bool, Date, arrays, etc.
    var name: String
    var location: String = "Franchises"

  #if DEBUG
    var tournamentData = [
        Tournament(name: "Season Opener"),
        Tournament(name: "May Day Tournament"),
        Tournament(name: "Memorial Day Tournament"),
        Tournament(name: "School's Out Tournament")
    ]
  #endif
}
```

```
struct TournamentListView: View {
    // should I use a different property wrapper if this is going to be something I refer to throughout the app?
    @State var tournaments = tournamentData 

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List(tournaments, id: \.name) { tournament in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: TournamentDetailView(tournaments: $tournaments, tournament: tournament),
                        label: { Text (tournament.name)}
                    )
                }

                Spacer()

                NavigationLink(
                    destination: TournamentDetailView(tournaments: $tournaments, addingNewTournament: true),
                    label: { Text ("Add a new tournament") }
                )
            }.navigationTitle("Tournaments")
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct TournamentDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var tournaments: [Tournament]
    @State var tournament = Tournament(name: "")
    var addingNewTournament: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Tournament Info")) {
                TextField("Name", text: $tournament.name)
                TextField("Location", text: $tournament.location)
            }
            Section {
                Button(action: {
                    if addingNewTournament { tournaments.append(tournament) }
                    presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                }) { Text(addingNewTournament ? "Create Tournament" : "Update Tournament") }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(P. S. I removed the second question about if my code is more or less good or if I'm not doing things "The SwiftUI Way" because my question was closed ("this will help others answer the question" my left foot!).  Another case of SO getting in its own way, being an obstacle to people learning rather than a vehicle for good. I asked a very specific question, but I also took the opportunity to ask if my approach was reasonable or not. This should NOT be something that admins police, especially since, the one reply I *did* get actually answered a question I DID NOT ASK, but had thought about, namely about Previews. So, let me get this straight: I can only ask a single question or I'm sanctioned, but people can answer *more* than was asked; they just need to be clairvoyant. That's nuts. I think the reply I got exemplifies the good parts of SO - people helping people and even going the extra mile. My second question of an obviously much more general nature was not going to confuse anyone who read my question.)

Answer (score 1):

First thing is, you should keep in mind that you have just one source of truth to drive your entire application. This source of truth will be passed around as an `EnvironmentObject`. So all your `tournamentData` will be inside this class. For example:

```
final class DataStore : ObservableObject{
   #if DEBUG
   @Published var tournamentData = [
        Tournament(name: "Season Opener"),
        Tournament(name: "May Day Tournament"),
        Tournament(name: "Memorial Day Tournament"),
        Tournament(name: "School's Out Tournament")
   ]
   #else
   @Published var tournamentData = [Tournament]()
   #endif 
}
```

This should be passed around from your top level view.

```
var body: some Scene {
   WindowGroup {
      ContentView()
           .environmentObject(DataStore())
   }
}
```

And just access this from each of your child views.

```
@EnvironmentObject var store : DataStore
```

Then you should just update this single source of truth and the `tournamentData` inside of it. Everything should work as expected.

I recommend seeing apple's WWDC SwiftUI videos. They explain it pretty well. Or if you want a more hands on approach first, go through [this](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) tutorial. It is amazing.

**Edit:** For completion sake, I think I should add in the proper method of handling `DEBUG` only code as well. The above will work but what you should really do is assign models for debugging inside the `PreviewProvider`. Apple removes it from production code anyways.

So inside your `View`:

```
struct Listing_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        
        let store = DataStore()
        store.tournamentData = [
            Tournament(name: "Season Opener"),
            Tournament(name: "May Day Tournament"),
            Tournament(name: "Memorial Day Tournament"),
            Tournament(name: "School's Out Tournament")
        ]
        
        return Listing().environmentObject(store)
    }
}
```

and remove the `#if DEBUG` from your `DataStore`

Comment: Thanks for this. I'll try in the morning. I agree the Apple tutorial's are amazing, and I'm actually going to steal the layout of the LandmarksDetailView for my UserProfileView. ;) I've seen the WWDC videos, but some of them do not age well, especially since SwiftUI is evolving so much, so fast. And THANK YOU for the extra bit about the `PreviewProvider` and debug data. That was a question I was going to ask, but forgot to ask. I'll try that, too!